# Plotting Direction Field for Differential Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How would I solve this problem?

Plot a direction field for the differential equation
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(x^2+y^2)\log(|x+y|)$ when $-1< x$, $y< 1$

Intervals of the plot must be all the same length and the grid is 20x20

---

I am brand new to mathematica so forgive me if this is easily done but I have been researching how to solve this problem for the last couple hours and have not been successful. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `VectorPlot` and with `StreamPlot`.

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^2 + y^2]*Log[Abs[x + y]];

VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]